# How to detect debug mode in t4 template?

Tags: c#, .net, t4

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="True" language="C#" #>
```

when debug is actually true I may want to write additional lines to the output file, can I somehow detect which way the debug flag is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
<#@ template debug="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Configuration" #>
<#
    #if DEBUG
#>
    I am in debug
<#
    #else
#>
    I am in release
<#
    #endif
#>
```

For `debug="true"` you should see "I am in debug", while for `debug="false"` the output will be "I am in release".